# azure authentication of multiple users in same tenant cause issue. first user's data is persisting when i login as second user

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I logged in as testuser1 into tenant1. Data is shown correct. UserPrincipal is correct.

I logged in as testuser2 into tenant1. Data is shown incorrect because UserPrincipal is still having details of first user.

Comment: How did you get the UserPrincipal and how did you do the authorization?

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be like this. You can use [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-java-native-headless/active-directory-java-native-headless/) to have a try.